# Dart 2 class with a constructor very similar to the polymorphism of other languages

Tags: dart, polymorphism

I need to represent a photo with a **Dart 2** class. The photo can be *rectangular* or *circular*. So, with a polymorphism I could write:

```
import 'dart:math';

class Photo {
  double width;
  double height;
  double radius;
  double area;

  Photo(double width, double height) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.area = width * height;
  }

  Photo(double radius) {
    this.radius = radius;
    this.area = pi * pow(radius, 2);
  }
}
```

So I could allow to create a Photo with radius or a Photo with width and height; ***no other option***.

How can I do this with **Dart 2**?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
import 'dart:math';

class Photo {
  final double area;

  // This constructor is library-private. So no other code can extend
  // from this class.
  Photo._(this.area);

  // These factories aren't needed – but might be nice
  factory Photo.rect(double width, double height) => new RectPhoto(width, height);
  factory Photo.circle(double radius) => new CirclePhoto(radius);
}

class CirclePhoto extends Photo {
  final double radius;

  CirclePhoto(this.radius) : super._(pi * pow(radius, 2));
}

class RectPhoto extends Photo {
  final double width, height;

  RectPhoto(this.width, this.height): super._(width * height);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Kevin! Your answer is *very* interesting. I’m curious to know why it would be nice to use factories, and why you decided to use them. Thanks!

Comment: If I create a Photo object in this way: `Photo photo = new CirclePhoto(15.0, 10.0);`, how can I get the radius from `photo` object? Can not I make the radius variable private and get it with a getter? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are coming from java, then following code will look familiar.

```
import 'dart:math';

abstract class Photo {
  double area();
}

class CircularPhoto extends Photo {
  double radius;

  CircularPhoto(this.radius);

  @override
  double area() {
    return pi * pow(this.radius, 2);
  }
}

class RectPhoto extends Photo {
  double length;
  double height;

  RectPhoto(this.length, this.height);

  @override
  double area() {
    return this.length * this.height;
  }
}

void main(){
  Photo p = new CircularPhoto(5);
  print(p.area());
}
```

You create abstract **photo** class with radius only (since **length** and **height** are specific to **RectPhoto** and radius is specific to **CircularPhoto**). Then create **RectPhoto**, **CircularPhoto** or any other implementation you'd like. Then @override area from Photo class.

Hope this is helpful.