# Dart 2.0.0 Access to the variable of a class that extends another

Tags: dart

I have these classes (as @KevinMoore showed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51677465/dart-2-class-with-a-constructor-very-similar-to-the-polymorphism-of-other-langua/51679021#51679021)):

```
import 'dart:math';

class Photo {
  final double area;

  // This constructor is library-private. So no other code can extend
  // from this class.
  Photo._(this.area);

  // These factories aren't needed – but might be nice
  factory Photo.rect(double width, double height) => new RectPhoto(width, height);
  factory Photo.circle(double radius) => new CirclePhoto(radius);
}

class CirclePhoto extends Photo {
  final double radius;

  CirclePhoto(this.radius) : super._(pi * pow(radius, 2));
}

class RectPhoto extends Photo {
  final double width, height;

  RectPhoto(this.width, this.height): super._(width * height);
}
```

My question is: if I create a `Photo` object in this way: `Photo photo = new CirclePhoto(15.0, 10.0);`, how can I get the `radius` from `photo` object? Can I make the `radius` variable private and get it with a getter?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need a `get` method :

```
class Rectangle {
  num left, top, width, height;

  Rectangle(this.left, this.top, this.width, this.height);

  // Define two calculated properties: right and bottom.
  num get right => left + width;
  set right(num value) => left = value - width;
  num get bottom => top + height;
  set bottom(num value) => top = value - height;
}

void main() {
  var rect = Rectangle(3, 4, 20, 15);
  assert(rect.left == 3);
  rect.right = 12;
  assert(rect.left == -8);
}
```

Doc: https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/language-tour

Comment: thank you, but my problem is different. Can you use my code to show me how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to cast the value to a `CirclePhoto` to access the `radius` value. A `Photo` does not have a radius, so if you do:

```
Photo photo = new CirclePhoto(15.0);
print(photo.radius); // Compile-time error, Photo has no "radius"
```

you get an error, but if you do:

```
Photo photo = new CirclePhoto(15.0);
print((photo as CirclePhoto).radius);
```

it works.

This performs a *down-cast* from `Photo` to `CirclePhoto`. The static type system cannot tell that this is safe (some photos are not circle-photos), so it checks at run-time. If the photo isn't actually a `CirclePhoto`, you get a run-time error.

Another option is to use type-check-based type promotion:

```
Photo photo = new CirclePhoto(15.0);
if (photo is CirclePhoto) print(photo.radius);
```

This promotes the `photo` variable to be a `CirclePhoto` in the code guarded by the `is`-check. (Type promotion is fairly primitive, it basically needs to be a local variable that you are not assigning to, and the type you check must be a sub-type of the current type of the variable).

Making `radius` private and adding a getter makes *no difference*. You already have a getter names `radius` on `CirclePhoto`, the one introduced by your final field. There is no advantage in renaming the field to be private and adding another getter, it's pure overhead.